# Excel Macro Copy Paste REF! Error

Tags: vba, excel

I am currently new to excel macros and trying to figure out why this is not working. Basically, I want Cell "D22" from "Sheet1" to be copied and then pasted to "sheet2" Cell "A2". The problem is on sheet1 I have a formula in cell D22 so when I copy and paste it into the new sheet, I get a #REF! ERROR   :(

I have looked it up and tried fixing it but still no luck. Below is my basic code. I know there is probably a simple solution but if someone could please advise me in the right direction much would be appreciated! xD

```
Sub Insert()
 Sheets("Sheet1").Select
 Range("D22").Select
 Selection.Copy
 Sheets("Sheet2").Select
 Range("A2").Select
 ActiveSheet.Paste
End Sub
```

Comment: What is the formula that you have in cell D22?

Comment: Hi YowE3K,  =SUM(D10-D11)-(D13*D12)

Comment: Do you mean to copy the formula `Sub Insert() : [Sheet2!A2] = [Sheet1!D22] : End Sub` ?

Comment: So, when that gets copied to A2, it will become `=SUM(A-10-A-9)-(A-7*A-8)`, but Excel doesn't understand rows of `-10` etc

Comment: No I want to copy the result of the formula

Comment: You just want to paste values?

Comment: So you want to do `Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A2").Value = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("D22").Value`?

Comment: exactly, it currently copies the formula and that's why I get the #ref!

Answer (score 3):

If you just want to assign the **value** of one cell to another, don't use copy/paste, just use the `Value` property:

```
Sub Insert()
    Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A2").Value = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("D22").Value
End Sub
```

Comment: Wow! Thank you YowE3k!